# Compare 2 differents conditions with the same idea

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have a question : what is the difference between : `$value !=''` and `!isset($value)` ?

Comment: `$value != ''` can return a notice if `$value` hasn't been declared. `!isset($value)` will not return a notice.

Comment: what's is the best practice of use : isset or != '' ?@Henders

Comment: For what? What are you trying to do? If you just want to check if `$value` is set then use `isset()` because that's what it's for. That doesn't mean it is anything other than declared though.

Comment: @HareaCosticla if people are answering your questions try to vote/accept them, at least comment so that other people get to know why you did not accepted the answers??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference in practical use between `$value != ''` and `!isset($value)` is that you can use `isset()` like this:

```
if(!isset($value)){
    echo '$value is not declared or is equal to null';
}
```

If `$value` is not actually set then you won't get a notice with `isset()`. If you did something like this:

```
if($value != ''){
    echo $value." is not equal to nothing"; 
}
```

If `$value` is not set then this will cause a notice in PHP explaining that `$value` has not yet been declared.

The thing to note is that `isset()` will check that the variable has been declared but will not check that it isn't equal to `''`.

---

**But what about `empty()`?**

The other part of the puzzle here would be `empty()` which will check whether a variable is declared and is not equal to `''`. You could do something like this:

```
if(!empty($value)){
    echo 'We know that $value is declared and not equal to nothing.';
}
```

which would be the same as doing this:

```
if(isset($value) && $value != ''){
    echo 'We know that $value is declared and not equal to nothing.';
}
```

---

**Further reading:**

`isset()` - [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

`empty()` - [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

isset, empty checks - [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623279/php-make-a-simple-if-isset-empty-function)

[Why check both isset and empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty)

<sub>All of these examples work in PHP 5.3+</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> **isset()** will tell you about the existence of the variable and is not `NULL`.
>
> **empty()** can tell you about both, existence of the variable & the value of the variable.

Ex.

```
$var1  = "";
echo isset($var1);
```

Output:- true

So to check if the variable was set then use `isset()` and if you want to check if the value of variable was not a null/empty use `empty()`.

`$value != ''` means you are checking if `$value` is not an empty string.

`!isset($value)` determine if a variable `$value` is not set and is `NULL`

Read these links for more information on `isset` & `empty`

[What's the difference between 'isset()' and '!empty()' in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582962/whats-the-difference-between-isset-and-empty-in-php)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: What's the difference between `$value != ''` and `!empty($value)`?

Comment: `empty($value)` Determine whether a variable `$value` (of any type) is empty, while `$value != ''` is specific to `string`

Answer (score 0):

`$variable != ''` simply checks variable against empty string value ( or null because `'' == null`), if variable is not defined notice will be shown.

`!isset($variable)` checks whether variable is defined and if it is not returns true, no error/notice will be shown.

---

But be aware that `isset` may return false even when variable is defined

```
$variable = null;
var_dump(isset($variable));  // prints false
```

[To check if variable is truly defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3803487/619616) within the current scope, use 'array_key_exists' with 'get_defined_vars'

```
$variable = null;
var_dump(array_key_exists('value', get_defined_vars()));  // prints true
```